# How to extract specific lines that starts with an predefined alphabet from multiple PDF files

Tags: r

The below code helps me pull first page of every PDF file from the directory.

```
library(pdftools)
    lapply(files, function(x) strsplit(pdf_text(x), "\n")[[1]]) -> result
```

Now I want to extract specific lines from these pages which starts with a predefined word.

For ex: I have this line "Source Program: lafaf_sfafatfga.sas" in PDF, now I want to extract only this line, similarly I want to extract at least 5 lines which starts with different words or alphabets in each line. So output should only have those 5 lines I ask for.

Please give me your inputs.

Thank you
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for the lines in the first page you can try with `lapply` as :

```
lapply(files, function(x) {
  tmp <- strsplit(pdf_text(x), "\n")[[1]]
  grep('Source Program: lafaf_sfafatfga.sas', tmp, value = TRUE)
}) -> result

result
```